# How to call an Async function as a Button Command in Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, python-asyncio

I'm having a problem with async function. I want to call the function with a command of a Tkinter button. Here's the Function:

```py
async def main():
        # Initializes the Deepgram SDK
    dg_client = Deepgram(DEEPGRAM_API_KEY)

    with open(PATH_TO_FILE, 'rb') as audio:
        source = {'buffer': audio, 'mimetype': MIMETYPE}
        options = {'punctuate': True, 'language': 'en-US'}

        print('Requesting transcript...')
        print('Your file may take up to a couple of minutes to process.')
        print('While you wait, did you know that Deepgram accepts over 40 audio file formats? Even MP4s.')
        print('To learn more about customizing your transcripts check out developers.deepgram.com')

        response = await dg_client.transcription.prerecorded(source, options)
        print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))

        mainText = str(response['results']['channels'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])

        url = "https://api.apilayer.com/text_to_emotion"
            # print(type(mainText))

        payload = mainText.encode("utf-8")
        headers = {
            "apikey": "lDeLNxJg**************"
        }

        response1 = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        status_code = response1.status_code
        result = response1.text

        print(result)
```

I tried two ways. Method 1:

```py
button_3 = Button(
    image=button_image_3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=asyncio.run(main()),
    relief="flat"
)
```

By this way, the function runs even the buttons is not clicked and the GUI is also freezing. The below method too is the same result:

```py
run_main = asyncio.run(main())

button_3 = Button(
    image=button_image_3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=run_main,
    relief="flat"
)
```

Please help, I'm stuck! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a generated code by an API. How should I change it? It returns errors when I do so.